# F#: Generating a word count summary

Tags: f#, word-count

I am new to programming and F# is my first .NET language.

I would like to read the contents of a text file, count the number of occurrences of each word, and then return the 10 most common words and the number of times each of them appears.

My questions are: Is using a dictionary encouraged in F#? How would I write the code if I wish to use a dictionary? (I have browsed through the Dictionary class on MSDN, but I am still puzzling over how I can update the value to a key.) Do I always have to resort to using Map in functional programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there's nothing wrong with the other answers, I'd like to point out that there's already a specialized function to get the number of unique keys in a sequence: `Seq.countBy`. Plumbing the relevant parts of [Reed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174328/f-generating-a-word-count-summary#29174641)'s and [torbonde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174328/f-generating-a-word-count-summary#29195418)'s answers together:

```
let countWordsTopTen (s : string) =
    s.Split([|','|]) 
    |> Seq.countBy (fun s -> s.Trim())
    |> Seq.sortBy (snd >> (~-))
    |> Seq.truncate 10

"one, two, one, three, four, one, two, four, five"
|> countWordsTopTen
|> printfn "%A" // seq [("one", 3); ("two", 2); ("four", 2); ("three", 1); ...]
```

Answer (score 4):

> My questions are: Is using a dictionary encouraged in F#?

Using a Dictionary is fine from F#, though it does use mutability, so it's not quite as common.

> How would I write the code if I wish to use a dictionary?

If you read the file, and have a string with comma separated values, you could 
parse using something similar to:

```
// Just an example of input - this would come from your file...
let strings = "one, two, one, three, four, one, two, four, five"
let words = 
    strings.Split([|','|]) 
    |> Array.map (fun s -> s.Trim())

let dict = Dictionary<_,_>()
words
|> Array.iter (fun w -> 
    match dict.TryGetValue w with
    | true, v -> dict.[w] <- v + 1
    | false, _ -> dict.[w] <- 1)

// Creates a sequence of tuples, with (word,count) in order
let topTen =
    dict
    |> Seq.sortBy (fun kvp -> -kvp.Value)
    |> Seq.truncate 10
    |> Seq.map (fun kvp -> kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks, Reed. I have a follow-up question: What is the difference between Seq.take and Seq.truncate? When should I use each?

Comment: @MY_G Seq.take will fail if there are less than 10 items in the collection - truncate will always succeed.  (In the above, seq.take would fail, since I didn't have >10 items ;) )

Answer (score 3):

I would say an obvious choice for this task is to use the `Seq` module, which is really one of the major workhorses in F#. As Reed said, using dictionary is not as common, since it is mutable. Sequences, on the other hand, are immutable. An example of how to do this using sequences is

```
let strings = "one, two, one, three, four, one, two, four, five"
let words =
  strings.Split([|','|]) 
  |> Array.map (fun s -> s.Trim())

let topTen =
  words
  |> Seq.groupBy id
  |> Seq.map (fun (w, ws) -> (w, Seq.length ws))
  |> Seq.sortBy (snd >> (~-))
  |> Seq.truncate 10
```

I think the code speaks pretty much for itself, although maybe the second last line requires a short explanation:
The `snd`-function gives the second entry in a pair (i.e. `snd (a,b)` is `b`), `>>` is the functional composition operator (i.e. `(f >> g) a` is the same as `g (f a)`) and `~-` is the unary minus operator. Note here that operators are essentially functions, but when using (and declaring) them as functions, you have to wrap them in parentheses. That is, `-3` is the same as `(~-) 3`, where in the last case we have used the operator as a function.

In total, what the second last line does, is sort the sequence by the negative value of the second entry in the pair (the number of occurrences).

Comment: In newer versions of F# this can be calculated using `Seq.countBy`